# Getting Values from Database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple doubt. 
I've two drop down fields one for states and other for cities. Im loading these two from my database where I have two tables with name states and cities. Also when I select one state cities are changed acordingly as I have written a jquery code too..
This is how I load all states into my select tag

```
<%= jl.select :state_id , State.all.map{|j| [j[:name], j[:id]]}, {class: 'select2'} %>
```

What I want is when I load that page intialy I dont want my cities field to be blank. I want it to be a dropdown list full of cities corresponding to some particular state_id.
So how should my select tag for cities should Look. City table contains name,id and state_id.

Comment: Get all the cities of your first state and then set into the drop down.But better way to do it through ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add id to your states dropdown

```
<%= jl.select :state_id , State.all.map{|j| [j[:name], j[:id]]}, {class: 'select2',id:'states_dropdown'} %>
```

Then your Cities dropdown should look as the following:

```
<%= jl.select :city_id , City.where(:state_id=> "specific_id").map{|j| [j[:name], j[:id]]}, {class: 'select2'} %>
```

and add this in your coffee script file

```
$("#states_dropdown").change ->
        $.ajax
            url: '/category/childrens'
            type: 'GET'
            data : 
                state_id: $(this).val()
            success: (data, status, response) ->
                #update cities dropdown
            error: ->
                # Hard error
```

Comment: is there any way that i can get the value of state_id which is stored from job_location table.. Like if i write p job.job_locations.first i get an output like #<JobLocation id: 22, job_id: 41, state_id: 2, city_id: 40034, created_at: "2014-03-25 10:00:45", updated_at: "2014-03-25 10:00:45"> in console. I want to extrat that state_id alone

Comment: Is that what you are asking for job.job_locations.first.state_id or i am getting you wrong ?

Comment: yeah almost all said d same answer.. but im getting error when i put something like <% p job.job_locations.first.state_id %>

undefined method `state_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This means that job.job_locations is an empty array

Comment: but what about the output i got wen i wrote p job.job_locations.first?

Comment: Can you post the output of job.job_locations from rails console

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<JobLocation id: 22, job_id: 41, state_id: 2, city_id: 40034, created_at: "2014-03-25 10:00:45", updated_at: "2014-03-25 10:00:45">]>
 Rendered companies/_job_skills.html.erb (4.3ms)
 Rendered companies/_job.html.erb (54.9ms) this is what i got from p job.job_locations

Answer (score 2):

you should write code on load.

```
var cities_obj_arr = <%= @cities.to_json %>;

$(document).on('change', "#state_select_box", function(){
  var state_id = $(this).val();
  var str_option = '';
  $.each(cities_obj_arr, function(index, city_obj){
     if(state_id == city_obj['city']['state_id']){
       str_option = str_option + "<option value='"+city_obj['city']['name']+"'">"+city_obj['city']['name']+"</option>"; /*city_obj['city']['name'] city is object name for cities*/
     }
  });
  $(this).html(str_opotion);
});
```

please have a look on image, it will help more.

[image]